# Automatically changing worksheet names

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to run a macro that will automatically rename my worksheets at the beginning of a new fiscal year. My worksheets are labeled JAN 18, FEB 18, MAR 18, etc. where 18 represents fiscal year 18. I have created a userform and when the month of OCT is selected, I want to have all sheets with 18 as the fiscal year to be increased to 19. The year after that, to 20. This can be daunting having to manually change these each year. Honestly, I have no idea how to even begin attempting this. I know that I will most likely need to loop through the worksheets and replace using some sort of variable. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Record a macro where you *manually* change a sheet name. 2) modify that code so that you can apply it within a loop against *all* worksheets in the book. 3) If/when you get stuck, post the code you're attempting to use in the body of this question and what specific problem/error you have (aka [MCVE]). Without that, you're basically just asking someone to do the work for you.

Comment: Are the sheet names always in this format? `MMM YY`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loop to complete your ask. The first `Case` is where you will list sheets that you want the code to **not** run on. For all other sheets, the macro will add 1 to the last two characters. Thus, this solution will be broke if the following format is not true for all target sheet names: `MMM YY`

If you have a `Userform` to start the procedure, you can simply call this macro from the `Userform`.

---

If there are sheets you want the macro to ignore, try something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewYear()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet1", "Sheet3" 
        'List any sheets that you want the macro to ignore here ^            

    Case Else
        ws.Name = Left(ws.Name, 3) & Chr(32) & Right(ws.Name, 2) + 1

Next ws

End Sub
```

---

If the macro should run on ALL sheets, you can reduce to

```
Sub NewYear()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Name = Left(ws.Name, 3) & Chr(32) & Right(ws.Name, 2) + 1 
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I went back and forth with converting the characters at the end of the string to an integer and then back to a string, which may not have been necessary, but in testing this worked:

```
Sub sheetRename()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
If IsNumeric(Right(ws.Name, 2)) Then
ws.Name = Left(ws.Name, Len(ws.Name) - 2) & CStr(CInt(Right(ws.Name, 2)) + 1)
End If
Next ws


End Sub
```

It also includes checking to see if the worksheet name actually ends in two numbers. Hope it helps.